# Modal with controller in Laravel

Tags: html, ajax, laravel, modal-dialog

Hey friends I am creating a simple modal to show me the data of a provider and honestly is costing me quite a lot; Can someone give me a hand?

modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog"
         role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal">Detalle del Proveedor: </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-stripped table-bordered table-hover" id="table-detalle-proveedores">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Apellido</th>
                            <th>Telefono</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Dirección</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

botton of modal

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-detalle-proveedores" data-id="{{ $proveedores->id }}"
   data-path="{{ route('admin.proveedores.item') }}" data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#myModal"
   data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
</a>
```

Route

```
Route::post('admin/proveedores/item', [
    'as'   => 'admin.proveedores.item',
    'uses' => 'ProveedoresController@Item']);
```

function of controller

```
public function item(Request $request)
{
    $items = Proveedores::select($request->id);

    return json_encode($items);
}
```

[image: main.js1]
[image: main.js2]

I was testing that one and others but the maximum that I get it to show me in the console an empty object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in your javascript you're passing the id as  `proveedores_id` but in your controller you're trying to access it with `$request->id`.

It might be an idea to have a look at https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/8

Secondly, with using just `select` you're just going to be returning a json encoded version of `Builder`.

To get your request to actually return an instance of `Proveedores` you would do something like:

```
public function item(Request $request)
{
    $item = Proveedores::findOrFail($request->id);

    return compact('item');
}
```

This also means you can remove the `for` loop inside your success method and simply access the data with `response.item.*` e.g.

```
function (response) {

    console.log(response)

    table.html('')

    var fila = "<tr>" +
            "<td>" + response.item.name + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + response.item.last_name + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + response.item.tel + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + response.item.address + "</td>" +
            "</tr>";

    table.append(fila);

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is the difference between find and findorfail?

Comment: @basosneo `find` will return `null` if it doesn't exist. `findOrFail()` will throw an exception that will eventually turn into a 404 response. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: Because I have it working with 'find', because with 'findorfail' do not work

Comment: @basosneo That's weird because `findOrFail` just uses `find` behind the scenes. What error are you getting?

Comment: I do not receive anything (neither error nor data) but with find if I receive the data of my suppliers

Comment: @basosneo Fair enough, just use `find()` then :)